# Banner image loading improperly

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

The banner image of my wordpress website is not loading properly. It first loads in the center of the container and only after around a second it stretches to fill the container. [Pic of the initial state (center)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp4B1.jpg) [Picture of the page properly loaded after a second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oufhI.jpg)

I tried to disable WP Rocket, cleared cache, that did not seem to help. I also tried replacing the image with other ones of different resolutions, but the outcome was the same. I would appreciate any help, and if you need any additional details I am happy to provide them! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the div is set to full width, depending on what page builder you use. It might also break because of some css or breakpoints overlaping, message me if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

I would evaluate what containers are being used within your CSS files.
Please remember that global aspects of you code will control issues such as these. Do remember that any container you have used can effect the issue you are having.

Perhaps re-writing the code and start using a more friendly format to fit the picture you are seeking.